# How to enter name form user with window.onload in if/else condition and print jsPDF certificate

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is all the functions.Is a quiz that gives you certificate if you take over 80.

(function($) {
$.fn.emc = function(options) {

```
    var defaults = {
      key: [],
      scoring: "normal",
      progress: true
    },
    settings = $.extend(defaults,options),
    $quizItems = $('[data-quiz-item]'),
    $choices = $('[data-choices]'),
    itemCount = $quizItems.length,
    chosen = [],
    $option = null,
    $label = null;
    
   emcInit();
    
   if (settings.progress) {
      var $bar = $('#emc-progress'),
          $inner = $('<div id="emc-progress_inner"></div>'),
          $perc = $('<span id="emc-progress_ind">0/'+itemCount+'</span>');
      $bar.append($inner).prepend($perc);
    }
    
    function emcInit() {
      $quizItems.each( function(index,value) {
      var $this = $(this),
          $choiceEl = $this.find('.choices'),
          choices = $choiceEl.data('choices');
        for (var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
          $option = $('<input name="'+index+'" id="'+index+'_'+i+'" 
   type="radio">');
          $label = $('<label for="'+index+'_'+i+'">'+choices[i]+'</label>');
          $choiceEl.append($option).append($label);
            
          $option.on( 'change', function() {
            return getChosen();
          }); 
        }
      });
    }
```

Choose answer function.You have to answer all questions to submit

```
        function getChosen() {
 

 chosen = [];
      $choices.each( function() {
        var $inputs = $(this).find('input[type="radio"]');
        $inputs.each( function(index,value) {
          if($(this).is(':checked')) {
            chosen.push(index + 1);
          }
        });
      });
      getProgress();
    }
```

Progress bar function

```
 function getProgress() {
          var prog = (chosen.length / itemCount) * 100 + "%",
              $submit = $('#emc-submit');
          if (settings.progress) {
            $perc.text(chosen.length+'/'+itemCount);  
            $inner.css({height: prog});
          }
          if (chosen.length === itemCount) {
            $submit.addClass('ready-show');
            $submit.click( function(){
              return scoreNormal();
            });
          }
        }
```

Calculate score function.if score ocer 80 a button Print me appear and i dont know how to put id in this and use it to print jsPDF.

```
function scoreNormal() {
          var wrong = [],
              score = null,
              $scoreEl = $('#emc-score');
          for (var i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
            if (chosen[i] != settings.key[i]) {
              wrong.push(i);
            }
          }
          $quizItems.each( function(index) {
            var $this = $(this);
            if ($.inArray(index, wrong) !== -1 ) {
                $this.removeClass('item-correct').addClass('item-incorrect');
            } else {
              $this.removeClass('item-incorrect').addClass('item-correct');
            }
          });
         var score_num = ((itemCount - wrong.length) / itemCount).toFixed(2) * 100;
          score = ((itemCount - wrong.length) / itemCount).toFixed(2) * 100 + "%";
          if( score_num >= 80){
            $scoreEl.html("<h5>You did Excellent! You scored "+score+"  </h5><img 
          src=\"./logos/star.png\" style='max-width: 35px;'> <h5 >(Gold)</h5> <button 
        onclick=jsPDF(); >Print Me!</button>" ).addClass('new-score');
            
          }else if(score_num <= 80 && score_num >= 40){
            
            $scoreEl.html("<h5>You did Good! You scored "+score+"   </h5><img 
        src=\"./logos/star2.png\" style='max-width: 35px;'>  <h5>(Silver) 
          </h5>").addClass('new-score');
          }else{
           
            $scoreEl.html("<h5>You could have done better! You scored "+score+"   </h5> 
           <img src=\"./logos/star3.png\" style='max-width: 35px;'>  <h5>(Bronze) 
           </h5>").addClass('new-score-bad');
          }
          
          $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 50);
        }

      
        window.onload=function(){
    
        var el=document.getElementById('my_text');
        el.onclick=function(){
            var my_text=prompt('Enter Full Name here');
            // if(my_text) alert(my_text);
            var doc = new jsPDF();
             doc.setTextColor(0,0,255);
             doc.setFontSize(10);
            var image="data:image/png;base64,
       ***
       var width = doc.internal.pageSize.getWidth()
       // doc.text('Centered text', width/2, 20, { align: 'center' })
        doc.text('BABBAT', width/2, 20, { align: 'center' })
        doc.text('Strategic Partnership for Adult Education',  width/2, 30, { align: 
        'center' })
        doc.text('Project Reference: E1AB544D-2019-1-IS01-KA204-051131', width/2, 40, 
        { align: 'center' })
        doc.text('Certificate of Participation',  width/2, 50, { align: 'center' })
        doc.text('This certifies that', width/2, 60, { align: 'center' })
        doc.text(my_text, width/2, 70, { align: 'center' })
        doc.setTextColor(0,0,0);

        doc.text('text', width/2, 110, {maxWidth: 90},{ align: 'center'})
        
        doc.text('Text', width/2, 193,  {maxWidth: 70},{ align: 'center' })
        doc.addImage(image1, 'PNG', 20, 90, 50, 50);
        doc.addImage(image2, 'PNG', 30, 170, 60, 60);
 

   


         doc.addImage(image, 'PNG', 10, 10, 40, 40);
      
        doc.save('Certificate.pdf');

     }
    };


   }
  }(jQuery));


  $(document).emc({
  key: ["1","1","1","1","1","1","2","1","1","1","1","2"]
  });
```